# Cordova WP8 bootstrap glyphicon not showing

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

Do you know, how fixed problem not showing glypicon in app on WP8 usign cordova ?
App on android working fine, but when deployed on WP8, not display icon.
Bootstrap v3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twitter bootstrap requires the usage of an external font - **glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf**. However in windows phone the usage of external fonts via **@font-face** is not allowed. This is the reason why you cannot upload your own TTF font in a phonegap application and the glyphicons are relying on such file.

You acn try and use http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ to generate a CUFON version of the font ot you can create png versios of the needed icons and use them as images.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This also proved helpful to me. I ended up using [GLYPHICONS FREE](http://glyphicons.com/), which includes png versions of some of the glypicons included with Bootstrap.